# What is this connector type

Tags: connector, identification

Could anybody help to identify this connector type? I know it is kind of old.

[image]

Comment: Did you search "5 pin round connector" or similar? There's a button here for "Does not show any research effort"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like 5-pin 180° [DIN connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector).

Comment: Pretty much the same as for old computer keyboards (pre-PS2).

Comment: It's used for older audio equipment, and still used for MIDI (communication between music synthesizers and related devices)

Comment: Considering the "living room-compatible surface finish" of the plastic around it: This is consumer audio equipment, probably. So, http://hardwarebook.info/DIN_Audio